# ModelState.AddModelError

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Am I missing something?  I am trying to return model validation errors from my web api update method like this

```
public void Update  public void UpdateModel(Models.Model entity) {
        ModelState.AddModelError("name","error");
        return;
```

However the JSON returned has no validation errors

For example in this article [enter link description here](http://blog.duc.as/tag/asp-net-web-api/)

When I try to use a validation filter as in the previous article on this link I get the error Action xxxxx has one or more filters applied that do not derive from `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`. Only authorization filters are supported on DataController Insert/Update/Delete actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ModelState` isnt accessible from your JSON, unless you specifically serialize it as such. It's more used from the `HtmlHelper` extensions behind the scenes. If you're attempting to update the UI as if the model state was marked as such, you're going about it all wrong. You can either:

1. Do a full post to the server and let it render the appropriate response
2. Take the json you get back and then style the fields as appropriate for that response.

Comment: I'm trying to get ValidationErros into the JSON that is returned in the same way as they appear with validation attributes in the model.  For example   ,"ValidationErrors":[{"__type":"System.Web.Http.Data.ValidationResultInfo, System.Web.Http.Data","Message":"tReleaseDate must be after current date","ErrorCode":0,"StackTrace":null,"SourceMemberNames":["tReleaseDate"]}